# Jquery Sort by element value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have this dom:

```
<ul id="appsList">
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>android</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>ios</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>facebook</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>android</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>ios</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>android</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>android</span></li>
</ul>
```

and I want to sort the list items by an array I got:

The array can be: `[ios,android,facebook]` and any other combination of it and not must contain all keys, can be just `[ios]`.

I want the list to be sorted by the array so if I have in it `[ios,android,facebook]` then the list will be sorted like this:

```
<ul id="appsList">
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>ios</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>ios</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>android</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>android</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>android</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>android</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span>facebook</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the closest we got, there is a bug there that I cannot solve, look at the first result, suppose to be ios instead of anroid.
https://plnkr.co/edit/9rAXxPvOMcd3pezIVJz9?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** :

**[Final Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/g1kXNIFpgHlHJqzr3XnA?p=preview)**

For example :

```
<li><span>some value</span> <span class="sort">android</span></li>
```

And use `.find("sort")`

---

You have to tweak the `.sort()` function,

```
var arr = ['ios','android','facebook'] ;

var $li = $('#appsList li').sort(function(a,b) {
      var firstValue = $(a).find('.sort').text();
        var secondValue = $(b).find('.sort').text();

        var first = arr.indexOf(firstValue);
        var second = arr.indexOf(secondValue);

        var output = (second === -1 && first > -1) ? -1 :
        (second > -1 && first === -1) ? 1 :
        (second === -1 && first === -1) ? firstValue > secondValue :
        (second > first ? 1 : -1);
        return output;
});

$('#appsList').html($li);
```

---

Example snippet.

```js
var arr = ['ios','android','facebook'] ;
    
var $li = $('#appsList li').clone().sort(function(a,b) {

        var firstValue = $(a).find('.sort').text();
        var secondValue = $(b).find('.sort').text();

        var first = arr.indexOf(firstValue);
        var second = arr.indexOf(secondValue);

        var output = (second === -1 && first > -1) ? -1 :
        (second > -1 && first === -1) ? 1 :
        (second === -1 && first === -1) ? firstValue > secondValue :
        (second > first ? 1 : -1);
        return output;
});

$('#resultAppsList').html($li)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Before sort : 
 <ul id="appsList">
    <li><span>some value</span> <span class="sort">android</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span class="sort">ios</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span class="sort">facebook</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span class="sort">android</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span class="sort">ios</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span class="sort">android</span></li>
    <li><span>some value</span> <span class="sort">android</span></li>
 </ul>

After sort :
<ul id="resultAppsList">
</ul>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that, in this case, `$(this).text()` will be exactly the same as `$(this).find('span').text()`, so you can reduce the chain a little to avoid unnecessary work; also, if you cache the text-property to use (`var textProp = 'textContent' in document? 'textContent' : 'innerText'`), then you could easily avoid jQuery in that portion and simply use `this[textProp]` to retrieve the text. But for those minor changes it's really not worth a separate answer to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I was going through a very difficult answer then I saw your answer perfectly using `sort()` and it blew my mind! well done

Comment: @DavidThomas, yes you are totally right. I have added that line to my answer. The reason why I did not use `$(this).text()` is that `li` might contain some text, and the result is based purely on content of `span`s. Your 2nd point too is valid.

Comment: Yeah, it's very much a case-by-case possibility, and should you have taken that approach without warning of the difficulties I imagine you'd have had comments pointing out that issue anyway. Some days you just can't win! ;-)

Comment: Updated **[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/TJbJZCRLs9lAa3CzwaLY?p=preview)** Ugh. Silly mistakes I made!

Comment: @ShaunakD can you help me with this question please:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247204/jquery-or-underscore-sorting-a-list-by-span-text?noredirect=1#comment63916786_38247204

Answer (score 0):

While this is, of course, perfectly possible in jQuery it's worth noting that jQuery cannot do things that the native DOM cannot; therefore to complement other answers I chose to offer a non-jQuery approach using ES5 in order to maintain compatibility with older browsers (though an ES6 alternative is offered later):

```
// caching the '#appsList' element:
var list = document.getElementById('appsList'),

  // working out which text-property is present in the browser
  // (Chrome and Firefox, to the best of my knowledge, support
  // both innerText and textContent; whereas IE < 9 supports
  // only innerText):
  textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',

  // retrieving an Array of the (element) children of the list,
  // using Array.prototype.slice() and Function.prototype.call()
  // to turn the collection of child elements into an Array;
  // we then sort the Array using Array.prototype.sort() and
  // its anonymous function:
  sorted = Array.prototype.slice.call(list.children, 0).sort(function(a, b) {
    // here we find the first/only <span> element in the previous
    // Array element ('a') and the first/only <span> in the current
    // ('b') element and comparing its text:
    return a.querySelector('span')[textProp] > b.querySelector('span')[textProp];
  }),

  // creating a documentFragment:
  fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

// iterating over the sorted Array of elements:    
sorted.forEach(function(el) {

  // appending a clone of the element ('el') to the
  // fragment (in order to show the before/after together):
  fragment.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
});

// retrieving the element to show the newly-sorted result:
document.getElementById('resultAppsList').appendChild(fragment);
```

```js
var list = document.getElementById('appsList'),
  textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
  sorted = Array.prototype.slice.call(list.children, 0).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.querySelector('span')[textProp] > b.querySelector('span')[textProp];
  }),
  fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

sorted.forEach(function(el) {
  fragment.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
});
document.getElementById('resultAppsList').appendChild(fragment);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
li {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0.2em 0;
}
span {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
ul::before {
  content: attr(data-state)': ';
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<ul id="appsList" data-state="Before">
  <li>1<span>android</span>
  </li>
  <li>2<span>ios</span>
  </li>
  <li>3<span>facebook</span>
  </li>
  <li>4<span>android</span>
  </li>
  <li>5<span>ios</span>
  </li>
  <li>6<span>android</span>
  </li>
  <li>7<span>android</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="resultAppsList" data-state="After">
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ptgd13xp/).

To bring the above a little more up-to-date for modern browsers, here we have the ES6 update (though I suspect it could probably be *even more* ES6-ified):

```
// using the let statement to initialise variables:
let list = document.getElementById('appsList'),
  textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',

  // using Array.from() to convert the Array-like collection into an
  // Array:
  sorted = Array.from(list.children).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.querySelector('span')[textProp] > b.querySelector('span')[textProp];
  }),
  fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

// using Arrow functions within the Array.prototype.forEach() call, since we're
// not using the 'this' keyword and it's pleasantly abbreviated:
sorted.forEach(el => fragment.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true)));

document.getElementById('resultAppsList').appendChild(fragment);
```

```js
let list = document.getElementById('appsList'),
  textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
  sorted = Array.from(list.children).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.querySelector('span')[textProp] > b.querySelector('span')[textProp];
  }),
  fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

sorted.forEach(el => fragment.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true)));
document.getElementById('resultAppsList').appendChild(fragment);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
li {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0.2em 0;
}
span {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
ul::before {
  content: attr(data-state)': ';
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<ul id="appsList" data-state="Before">
  <li>1<span>android</span>
  </li>
  <li>2<span>ios</span>
  </li>
  <li>3<span>facebook</span>
  </li>
  <li>4<span>android</span>
  </li>
  <li>5<span>ios</span>
  </li>
  <li>6<span>android</span>
  </li>
  <li>7<span>android</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="resultAppsList" data-state="After">
</ul>
```

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).
- [Conditional (Ternary) Operator (`assessment ? ifTrue : ifFalse`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`Document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).
- [`Document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
- [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- [`'property' in Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).
- [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Comment: This is the closest we got to the solution:
https://plnkr.co/edit/9rAXxPvOMcd3pezIVJz9?p=preview